# How to set height of DIV with CSS in relative positioning?

Tags: css, css-float

I have some HTML+CSS code that wants to layout several `div`s. The layout is like this: all `div`s stay in a parent `div` whose size is fixed. Then each child `div` should stay on its own line, and use the minimum height for drawing its content. The last `div` should consume all remaining height, so that the parent `div` is entirely filled.

This code shows my approach using CSS `float` and `clear` properties:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .container {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      border: 3px solid black;
    }
    
    .top {
      background-color: yellow;
      float: left;
      clear: left;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .bottom {
      background-color: blue;
      height: 100%;
      float: left;
      clear: left;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="top">top1</div>
    <div class="top">top2</div>
    <div class="top">top3</div>
    <div class="top">top4</div>
    <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

However, the last `div` overflows from the its parent. I guess it is because of the `width: 100%`.

Is there any way to solve this problem? I want to avoid setting the `overflow` attribute of the parent, and also I have to avoid using absolute positioning. If somehow I could trick the last `div` to use the height of the parent minus the sum of height of the other `div`s.

Comment: This is floated positioning, not relative positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
div.container { overflow: hidden; }
```

It's not overflowing because it's 100% width. It's overflowing because it's a float and thus removed from the normal layout. Changing the overflow property will change how the browser caters for contained floats.

Oh and if you aren't already, make sure you're using a DOCTYPE. It particularly matters for IE.

Comment: Thanks! 

Yes, but this will hide a part of the bottom DIV, which I want to avoid. In principle I can have some things aligned at the bottom of the blue DIV, and they should also show. What I would like is to just stretch down the blue DIV vertically.